NEXTJS :GET http://localhost:3000/highLightTitle.png 404 (Not Found) content.js:199
I have a next js project and my code has nothing with GET http://localhost:3000/highLightTitle.png inside project but my project still gives an error about this issue this is error
inside content.js:199g)
has nothing with GET http://localhost:3000/highLightTitle.png inside project but my project still gives an error about this issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Look at the stack of the request to figure out what triggered it. You can see the stack when hovering the source code line displayed in the network tab.

This is caused by a Chrome browser extension, and this error has nothing to do with your Next.js project. If you don't want to be bothered by this error, you can try disabling the extension. In my case, the Monica extension triggered this error.

which extension?

It appears to be NiceGui based on this bug report.

You want to keep your images in /public folder. lets say
/public
 - imageone.png
 - imagetwo.png

In order to use those images
<Image src='/imageone.png' alt='profile' />


it would have been more helpfull if you had add screenshot of folder structure.

no i don't want but i check every thing and this method GET http://localhost:3000/highLightTitle.png is exist in my code ????

please check the path for the image, looks like you have not placed the image in public folder.

but i don't know why my code get http://localhost:3000/highLightTitle.png
i have not anything with that method GET. I don't know why this thing is exist in my code

when you access the application from browser, the images should  be downloaded from your web server. for ex http://localhost:3000 is your web server where your code is running. When you access the application URL the page which renders the images should be downloaded to browser in order to display. So when you use the image tag with valid source  in your code, a request will be initiated to webserver to download the image.
